# How can I verify that a downloaded Debian ISO image is correct?

Tags: security, debian

I've just downloaded `debian-504-i386-businesscard.iso` from a mirror and wanted to be sure that the file is OK.

The [Debian CD FAQ](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#verify) says:

> For HTTP or FTP downloads, use the
>   md5sum utility to calculate the
>   checksums of the files you downloaded,
>   then compare them to the checksums in
>   the MD5SUMS files which are
>   distributed alongside the jigdo
>   files of official releases.

["jigdo files of official releases"](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/) is a link to a download area but there are only md5sums for the live versions.

Am I missing something or are the md5sums for all Debian ISOs (except live CDs) really missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `MD5SUM` file. You will see

```
d359c8e33e29b2bc3833046b0625a02f  debian-504-i386-CD-1.iso
b2916f09a44b7632e44c2e02b0a8abc6  debian-504-i386-CD-10.iso
6fb72493a15a52ec331d970529bce349  debian-504-i386-CD-11.iso
3d674d36e13361e2a63b13c11f9b7648  debian-504-i386-CD-12.iso
189ee9b7dae9676e311502bd854fb626  debian-504-i386-CD-13.iso
13f1860db17101fb2ea7c9577607f7a6  debian-504-i386-CD-14.iso
de9ba8cfaf1a6a230e09784f07ce9f39  debian-504-i386-CD-15.iso
ef06f05acb4aca82627b88f5e9bec53f  debian-504-i386-CD-16.iso
67c84fde644d8ada29ccf9af1fd5446a  debian-504-i386-CD-17.iso
cbf1821fd25040133f4a353bb73a4d83  debian-504-i386-CD-18.iso
c79037209733e5db2771f860084fe439  debian-504-i386-CD-19.iso
407803df6857653eb2aa8236e9504b4c  debian-504-i386-CD-2.iso
1d4a2c5afeb0a0b90f1a25de74fc3d75  debian-504-i386-CD-20.iso
412f28f98829176ace48113dae1f1bcd  debian-504-i386-CD-21.iso
dbd3f26f02aa53d0125d3af149244ed2  debian-504-i386-CD-22.iso
2cffc7baea1a42497c31346e9d78237e  debian-504-i386-CD-23.iso
6c2d473b10e5e851d90e4914c501c34d  debian-504-i386-CD-24.iso
e0e65a5548b2a85665497184e0bd3fd3  debian-504-i386-CD-25.iso
4ce331d420044026cfd22c29137345ec  debian-504-i386-CD-26.iso
c0976b25b0b1035f8df396170c905083  debian-504-i386-CD-27.iso
439926e65066241b553b6d4e00a38fe4  debian-504-i386-CD-28.iso
ab4dc35c042e832e048d8f3fa4d9d2f0  debian-504-i386-CD-29.iso
13d4ab80b1fd1a8a2743c1f2f2ecddce  debian-504-i386-CD-3.iso
1d11d4d0d3976643c91119026df55e3f  debian-504-i386-CD-30.iso
e287369bee280f4efed4dd683c8fcf86  debian-504-i386-CD-31.iso
c8b5402c2aa9e1348558535d26b15877  debian-504-i386-CD-4.iso
1c3ecc23395155de7ee4171d10c1a061  debian-504-i386-CD-5.iso
46986bc17b3cab1b33433a6efb411dc4  debian-504-i386-CD-6.iso
df97f52c3469f849ff14a3d07eba284c  debian-504-i386-CD-7.iso
2851aced30c59c8f0db7e6156d47fe0e  debian-504-i386-CD-8.iso
07cfc2b463956fafa457cd65ddef6d14  debian-504-i386-CD-9.iso
f0bd15d662ad1aa751c70c1cc01fe76d  debian-504-i386-businesscard.iso
fd0424739359671f840cb87c14304bc6  debian-504-i386-kde-CD-1.iso
96d01d5f287c93d252c0ad73006b5ab8  debian-504-i386-netinst.iso
37084a93a23d11520534dc4a90324981  debian-504-i386-xfce+lxde-CD-1.iso
4427c95516d7f156a365e422c0e8e19c  debian-update-5.0.4-i386-CD-1.iso
cea1038fdfbc17e0ad743f6ffe9c8300  debian-update-5.0.4-i386-CD-2.iso
7b76a81bf893ebc363b9a348ee638b9a  debian-update-5.0.4-i386-CD-3.iso
f16e5019dec307b3453ec65818ce04a3  debian-update-5.0.4-i386-CD-4.iso
70e9c02883bd557d6bc864068621d925  debian-update-5.0.4-i386-CD-5.iso
f38abc68dc9dae0cad226e3da73a9c5e  debian-update-5.0.4-i386-CD-6.iso
```

Specifically

```
f0bd15d662ad1aa751c70c1cc01fe76d  debian-504-i386-businesscard.iso
```

Comment: I must be blind. Where exactly is the MD5SUM file? It's not in http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/5.0.4/i386/bt-cd/

Comment: @Ludwig: I found it in [another directory](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/5.0.4/i386/iso-cd/). I figured that `{distro}/{arch}/{iso-cd}`.

Comment: Thanks Josh, it's really there and the md5 matches the file I downloaded:-)